# Weird Loop While scanf

Tags: c, while-loop

I wrote this code. It must read an integer,  between 1 and 4(defined as lower-bound and upper-bound on the function), and if the condition fails, prints some error message and asks the question again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int varcheck(double x, char z, int lowerbound, int upperbound);

int main(){

    double playerCount;
    char i;

    printf("Insert Number of Players: ");
    scanf("%lf%c", &playerCount, &i);

    while(varcheck(playerCount, i, 1, 4) == 0){
        printf("Invalid Number of Players\n");
        printf("Insert Number of Players: ");
        scanf("%lf%c", &playerCount, &i);
    } 
    // ...Code continues...
}




int varcheck(double x, char z, int lowerbound, int upperbound){
    double r = 0;
    r = x - (int)x;  /*If r == 0 then its not decimal number*/ 

    if(r != 0 || z != '\n' || x < lowerbound || x > upperbound){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Function enters in some weird loop, can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: The lack of indentation here is really frustrating. That helps communicate not only structure but intent.

Comment: I don’t really know how to work with the stack overflow writing code, I’m sorry I’m new around here

Comment: The formatting of the code is fine, but you don't appear to indent any of it according to [standard practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). It's all slammed hard left on here, and perhaps in your original source as well.

Comment: I couldn’t use TAB, I’m sorry

Comment: Instead of writing the code in the editor, just copy-paste from whatever editor you normally use. Highlight and click the `{}` button to properly indent it for you automatically.

Comment: As a note, lines like `scanf("%lf%c, &playerCount, &i);` contain syntax errors. That string `"%lf...` is never closed. Maybe this isn't the code you actually used, in which case it's not as helpful as copy-pasting the code you did use that presumably compiled. This is why a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important, especially with C code. If we can't compile it, we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: how many times will a game have 3.25223421 players?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if you enter that number the code should ask again for the number of players

Comment: @tadman what do mean by it isn’t closed?

Comment: @AntonioMartins it would be probably easier to just scan a `%d`ecimal `int`eger

Comment: Where's the closing double quotation mark? There isn't one in the code you posted.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if u scan a decimal integer and you enter 2.5 it rounds up to 2, but the program should tell u that the  number entered isn’t correct

Comment: @tadman yes I’ve noticed that now, yes it was a mistake copying

Comment: What they're saying is that you're using a `double` to represent the number of players. You probably mean `size_t` since it's going to be a non-negative, non-floating point value.

Comment: @tadman So I should replace the double part with size_t?

Comment: Unless it's possible to have 3.25223421 players, yes, that'd make more sense. You may want to use `scanf("%d\n", &playerCount)` to keep this simple.

Comment: "Function enters in some weird loop, can anyone help me fix this?" well,  first you need to tell exactly what input you give to the program when you get into the "weird loop".

Comment: @4386427 It continuously print out enter number of players

Comment: @AntonioMartins ok but what is the input?

Comment: @4386427 For aaaa2,  it prints out enter number of players continuously

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, this code is a total mess to hunt through.

1. You haven't terminated any quoted sections (in `printf`s and `scanf`s)
2. No indentation
3. Using `double` for `playerCount`
4. And as it's a `double`, it's value maybe something like `12.000001` and hence `r` may never be `0`.
5. I'd suggest using `getchar` instead of `scanf` when you have to analyze characters like `\t`, `\n` and "" (space).
6. I'd say check this section again : `x < lowerbound || x > upperbound` because I think you intended to do this : `x > lowerbound || x < upperbound`

Fix these issues and your code should work fine I guess. Indentation has nothing to do with accuracy though.

Comment: Point 6 is wrong. Notice that the while-loop uses `== 0`

Comment: I said "I think you might have intended that"... It was just a suggestion to check that again. We all do mistakes. It's nothing new.

Comment: My point is that you should not give that suggestion as that part of OPs code is correct. BTW: I don't understand your point 4 either. If the input is 12.00001 OP wants to reject the input and that is in fact what will happen. There are other important errors in the code that you could mention. Example: what happens in the input is "abcd"

Comment: @4386427 Yes exactly.

Comment: @4386427 It's not the input. Anyway, you can remove those points if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The function `scanf` is a bit difficult to use for parsing user input. One problem is that `scanf` leaves the input stream intact/unchanged if it can't parse the object you ask. Example - if you input "aaa2" and try to scan for a float `scanf` will give you zero results and the input stream will still hold "aaa2". Consequently, the next `scanf` will also see the data "aaa2" and you have an endless loop.

The solution is to flush the input stream when a conversion fails. That could be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void flushInput()
{
    // Keep reading from input stream until a newline is read
    int c;
    do
    {
        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF) exit(1);
    } while (c != '\n');
}

int getInt()
{
    int n;
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
        // scanf will return 2 if the conversion is succesful, i.e.
        // if it could scan first an integer and then a character
        if (scanf("%d%c", &n, &c) == 2 && c == '\n') return n;

        // Conversion failed so flush the input stream
        flushInput();
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    int lowerbound = 1;
    int upperbound = 4;
    do
    {
        n = getInt();
    } while (n < lowerbound || n > upperbound);
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
4.2

aaaa2
9
3a
2
```

Output:

```
n=2
```